# How to get a class object instance to delete itself in Lotus Script?

Tags: class, lotusscript

Lotus Script does not normally allow a class to call its own Delete() procedure.

Only when the code that has references to the object gets all these references unused the garbage collector deletes it.

Is there a work around to this?

E.g.:

```
Class MySuicidalClass
    Sub New()
    End Sub

    Sub Delete()
    End Sub

    Public Sub KillMyself()

        Call Me.Delete()    'Error: Illeagal call to Delete

        Delete Me   'Error: Variable required (Me)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an external procedure that deletes the object, the class instance can call it to kill itself.

This effectively sets all references to the object instance to Nothing.

Like this:

```
'In the module level:
Private Sub DeleteObjectInstance(Obj As Variant)
    Delete Obj
End Sub


Class MySuicidalClass
    Sub New()
    End Sub

    Sub Delete()
    End Sub

    Public Sub KillMyself()

        Call DeleteObjectInstance(Me)   'This works!

    End Sub

End Class

Sub Test
    Dim sc As MySuicidalClass
    Set sc = New MySuicidalClass

    Call sc.KillMyself()

    MsgBox "sc is Nothing = " & CStr(sc Is Nothing) 'shows: TRUE

End Sub
```